# MySQL looping through dates and generating recordset columns

Tags: mysql, date, loops

Given these two tables:

```
tblHotels:
id INT
hotel_name VARCHAR
booking_open_date DATETIME
booking_close_date DATETIME

tblRegistrantHotelDates:
id INT
registrant_id INT
hotel_id INT
booking_date DATETIME
```

... where each entry in *tblRegistrantHotelDates* represents a registrant staying at a hotel for a single night ( so a registrant staying two nights would have two rows in the table with the same hotel ID and a different booking_date)...

How can I get a set of results in this format:

```
registrant_id,hotel_id,3rd March,4th March,5th March
42,6,1,0,1
57,6,1,1,0
```

... where the column names are generated by looping from *tblHotels.booking_open_date* to *tblHotels.booking_close_date* (I'm not bothered about the exact date format of the column name), and the 1/0 in each of the date columns indicates whether or not the registrant will be staying at that hotel on that date?

NB: Not all hotels will have the same booking open/close dates, although they WILL always overlap. So the generated column names must go from the opening date for the earliest hotel to the closing date for the latest one.

Is this even possible in SQL?

EDIT - this is what I've got. It doesn't put the dates as the column names, it will only work for as many dates as I explicity query for, and it's an appallingly clunky and slow mess. To anyone else looking for a similar solution: this is how NOT to do it. Hopefully, someone who knows what to do will be along soon:

```
SELECT
reg.first_name,
reg.last_name,

MIN(h.booking_open_date) AS day_1,
(
    SELECT 1 FROM tblRegistrantHotelDates rh
    WHERE rh.hotel_id = h.id
    AND rh.registrant_id = reg.id
    AND rh.hotel_date = MIN(h.booking_open_date)
) AS day_1_booked,

CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(MIN(h.booking_open_date),INTERVAL 1 DAY) < MAX(h.booking_close_date) THEN
    DATE_ADD(MIN(h.booking_open_date),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
END AS day_2,
(
    SELECT 1 FROM tblRegistrantHotelDates rh
    WHERE rh.hotel_id = h.id
    AND rh.registrant_id = reg.id
    AND rh.hotel_date = DATE_ADD(MIN(h.booking_open_date),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS day_2_booked,

CASE WHEN DATE_ADD(MIN(h.booking_open_date),INTERVAL 2 DAY) < MAX(h.booking_close_date) THEN
    DATE_ADD(MIN(h.booking_open_date),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
END AS day_3,
(
    SELECT 1 FROM tblRegistrantHotelDates rh
    WHERE rh.hotel_id = h.id
    AND rh.registrant_id = reg.id
    AND rh.hotel_date = DATE_ADD(MIN(h.booking_open_date),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
) AS day_3_booked,

## etc etc...

MAX(h.booking_close_date) AS day4,
(
    SELECT 1 FROM tblRegistrantHotelDates rh
    WHERE rh.hotel_id = h.id
    AND rh.registrant_id = reg.id
    AND rh.hotel_date = MAX(h.booking_close_date)
) AS day_4_booked

FROM tblRegistrants reg
LEFT JOIN tblRegistrantHotelDates hd ON hd.registrant_id = reg.id
LEFT JOIN tblHotels h ON hd.hotel_id = h.id
GROUP BY reg.id
```

Comment: have you tried something ? or u dont want loose your power ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Loose my power?